# Property bluetooth does not exist on type ‘Navigator'

Tags: angular, web-bluetooth

I integrated [sample code](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-information-characteristics.html) into my Angular 6 project. But there some compile errors. One of these errors is:
Property 'bluetooth' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Why this error happens and how can I solve it?

Comment: Gonna need some code..

Comment: this means that navigator object doesn't have any property named 'bluetooth', if you have navigator as an interface or class in typescript , just add that property to solve it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this below module to install types of web-bluetooth api. Which you can use to define types of navigator blutooth api objects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web-bluetooth

Now if you need not specify the exact type of navigator object (& its properties) then you can do following:

```
let mobileNavigatorObject: any = window.navigator;
if(mobileNavigatorObject && mobileNavigatorObject.bluetooth) {
  // Here write your logic of mobileNavigatorObject.bluetooth.requestDevice();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why this error happens but you can fix it by installing the types,`npm install --save-dev @types/web-bluetooth`, and using a triple-slash directive, `/// <reference types="web-bluetooth" />`, like so:

```js
/// <reference types="web-bluetooth" />

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myApp';

  async test() {
    try {
      const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        filters: [
          {
            namePrefix: 'test',
          },
        ],
        optionalServices: ['test'],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the following npm module:

`npm install --save @types/web-bluetooth`

and insert this row in the top of your code:

`/// <reference types="web-bluetooth" />`

Plus if you receive the following error:

> Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'Bluetooth': Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request.

You have too call the bluetooth function from a user call, ex. call the function from a button.