# Web-Bluetooth: custom typings for navigator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, web-bluetooth

I'm writing an browser application for my device which will communicate via bluetooth.

Can someone help me with typescript typings?

I'm trying to access bluetooth property in `navigator` object:

```
let mobileNavigatorObject: Navigator = navigator;
        mobileNavigatorObject.bluetooth.requestDevice(
            {
                filters: [
                    {
                        namePrefix: "My",
                    }
                ],
                optionalServices: ["service uuid"]
            }
        )
```

but i've got: `error TS2339: Property 'bluetooth' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.`

even after installing @type/web-bluetooth

There are 2 types sources `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`

```
interface Navigator extends NavigatorID, NavigatorOnLine, NavigatorContentUtils, NavigatorStorageUtils, MSNavigatorDoNotTrack, MSFileSaver, NavigatorBeacon, NavigatorConcurrentHardware, NavigatorUserMedia, NavigatorLanguage, NavigatorStorage, NavigatorAutomationInformation {
    readonly activeVRDisplays: ReadonlyArray<VRDisplay>;
    readonly authentication: WebAuthentication;
    readonly cookieEnabled: boolean;
    readonly doNotTrack: string | null;
    gamepadInputEmulation: GamepadInputEmulationType;
    readonly geolocation: Geolocation;
    readonly maxTouchPoints: number;
    readonly mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray;
    readonly msManipulationViewsEnabled: boolean;
    readonly msMaxTouchPoints: number;
    readonly msPointerEnabled: boolean;
    readonly plugins: PluginArray;
    readonly pointerEnabled: boolean;
    readonly serviceWorker: ServiceWorkerContainer;
    readonly webdriver: boolean;
    getGamepads(): (Gamepad | null)[];
    getVRDisplays(): Promise<VRDisplay[]>;
    javaEnabled(): boolean;
    msLaunchUri(uri: string, successCallback?: MSLaunchUriCallback, noHandlerCallback?: MSLaunchUriCallback): void;
    requestMediaKeySystemAccess(keySystem: string, supportedConfigurations: MediaKeySystemConfiguration[]): Promise<MediaKeySystemAccess>;
    vibrate(pattern: number | number[]): boolean;
}
```

and `node_modules/@types/web-bluetooth/index.d.ts`

```
interface Navigator {
    bluetooth: Bluetooth;
}
```

tsConfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

How to choose correct one?

Comment: Did you give the browser permission to access bluetooth?

Comment: yep, it works with navigator type of any.
And my issue relates to typescript compiling, not browser.

Comment: It works without permission request, to be honest.

Comment: Yep, `error TS2339: Property 'bluetooth' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.` it is typescript error, not runtime. 
I didn't found out how to use Navigator interface from @type/web-bluetooth package. It uses default one from typescript package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property bluetooth does not exist on type ‘Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298406/property-bluetooth-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator)